# SF: from UTM to latitude/longitude

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a set of UTM metric points that I would like to convert to latitude and longitude decimal points using the sf environment.

The dataset I have looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(longitude=c(4585434,4588904,4586694),
                 latitude=c(430060.8,430960.8,432427.2),
                 street=c("74 JOSEP SERRANO", "30 LLOBERA","4 SANT ILDEFONS"),
                 number=c(45,68,34))
```

I have only been able to do it under the sp framework.

```
dfevpo <- SpatialPoints(df[, c("longitude","latitude")], proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10")) 
longlats <- spTransform(dfevpo, CRS("+proj=longlat")) #transform

longlats.df <- as.data.frame(longlats)
longlats.df$.id <- as.numeric(rownames(longlats.df))
```

However, the resulting `longlats.df` dataset does not include all variables from the original dataset. I guess the order is the same and I could merge it with the original one. However, is there a more intuitive way of doing this? Ideally, I would like to use sf.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code

```
library(sp)

df <- data.frame(longitude=c(4585434,4588904,4586694),
                 latitude=c(430060.8,430960.8,432427.2),
                 street=c("74 JOSEP SERRANO", "30 LLOBERA","4 SANT ILDEFONS"),
                 number=c(45,68,34))

#Convert the data frame to SpatialPointsDataFrame
coordinates (df)= ~longitude + latitude

#Assign a projection to it
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10")

#Projection transformation
longlats <- spTransform(df, CRS("+proj=longlat")) 

#Convert it to data frame
longlats.df <- as.data.frame(longlats)
```

If you want to implement the whole thing using `sf` package, you can use the following code

```
df <- data.frame(longitude=c(4585434,4588904,4586694),
                 latitude=c(430060.8,430960.8,432427.2),
                 street=c("74 JOSEP SERRANO", "30 LLOBERA","4 SANT ILDEFONS"),
                 number=c(45,68,34))

#Conversion of data frame to sf object
df_sf <- st_as_sf(x = df,                         
                  coords = c("longitude", "latitude"),
                  crs = "+proj=utm +zone=10")

#Projection transformation
sfc = st_transform(df_sf, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

#Convert it to data frame
sfc_df <- as.data.frame(sfc)
```