# Coordinates to UTM with R

Tags: r, geospatial

```
p<-c("a","b","c")
x<-c("41.434931824218786","41.42672694456612","41.647157029217425")
y<-c("2.1759165563219116","2.1954430374270455","1.4942063178224638")
df<-data.frame(p,x,y)
```

I want to convert these coordinates into UTMX y UTMY.

Comment: check out the `sf` package...similar question but going the other direction here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106215/sf-from-utm-to-latitude-longitude

Comment: Should those points end up in Spain or Somalia? For lat/lon coordinates x usually marks longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use directly `st_as_sf` indicating the columns with the x and y coordinates, as well as its crs. Also, if you wish to retain the other columns info (e.g., p column) you can use `mutate` to add the coordinates as new columns. Finally, if you are no longer interested in the geometry column, you can remove it using `st_drop_geometry`.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

df |>
# Transform df from data frame to sf object
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"),
           crs = 4326) |>
  # Reproject data to new crs
  st_transform(23031) |>
  # Obtain coordinates as new columns
  mutate(coords = st_coordinates(geometry)) |>
  # Drop geometry column
  st_drop_geometry()

#  p  coords.X  coords.Y
#1 a 5137810.8  307601.4
#2 b 5136560.9  310324.5
#3 c 5170504.7  211895.1
```